# How do I force Sublime text 3 to cycle through bookmarks in the current document?

Tags: sublimetext3, bookmarks

This is driving me nuts. I'm relatively new to Sublime text 3 so bear with me.

I accidentally toggled something that forced the F2 key to cycle through bookmarks in multiple files, including reopening closed files that have bookmarks.

How do I force sublime to cycle through bookmarks in the current document only?

Comment: if you type `sublime.log_commands(True)` in the ST console (View menu -> Show Console), and then press F2, what is the output in the console?

Comment: You may also consider asking on the [Sublime Text forums](https://forum.sublimetext.com/).

Comment: It starts with: [<Sublime Bookmarks.bookmark.Bookmark object at 0x0000025B3A071278>, <Sublime Bookmarks.bookmark.Bookmark object at 0x0000025B3BD8A860>, <Sublime Bookmarks.bookmark.Bookmark object at 0x0000025B3A4EAE80>, <Sublime Bookmarks.bookmark.Bookmark object at 0x0000025B3B7E26D8>, <Sublime Bookmarks.bookmark.Bookmark object at 0x0000025B3B76A320>, <Sublime Bookmarks.bookmark.Bookmark object at 0x0000025B3A5120B8>, <Sublime Bookmarks.bookmark.Bookmark object at 0x0000025B3A071780>, and the keeps going (can't enter it all in the comment.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the [SublimeBookmark](https://github.com/bollu/sublimeBookmark#visibility-modes) package installed. According to the webpage you can make the F2 key only go to bookmarks in the current file by doing the following:

> Press `ctrl + shift + P` on Windows / Linux or `cmd + shift + P` on Mac and select `SublimeBookmarks:Show Only Bookmarks In Current File`